# Data repeating in android list view

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I have a list view whose adapter is in a different class in a different package. Now I have to get the data from database  then I set Adapter for my list view using this data. So I have created an ArryList and pass this in the constructor of Adapter while seeting it for the list view. But the problem is that the data is repeating. eg.-  there are 12 distinct Strings in the arraylist but what I get is -first five elements in order and after that the same five are being repeated. The count of data is always right but the position will always be 0,1,2,3,4 . I can not understand what the problem is . here is the code -

```
public class CheckboxAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    LayoutInflater inflater ;
    ArrayList<String> mData = new ArrayList<String>();

    //constructor for lesion adapter
    public CheckboxAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<String> data){
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mData = data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            Log.v("pos", ""+position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.e_lesion_liststyle, null);          
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.disease_lesion_checkbox);
            cb.setText(mData.get(position));
            cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_1);
                }
            });
        }//end of if condition
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Ankit can you also paste code for class where you are fetching data from db and creating mData arraylist.

Comment: hi rahul ! Actually I have checked that part. That's ok. I am getting correct data from the db and also when I pass the Arraylist in constructor it does hold valid data. Only when I am setting the data to my list view on the line cb.settext(mData.get(position)); This problem is coming because the position indexes are always the same i.e. 0,1,2,3,4

Comment: ok, how many rows are visible on the screen at a time. Is it 5-6?

Comment: problem solved. The problem was with convertView only as rightly stated by Vineet. I was checking for the condition if convetView != null and setting the data there itself, which is incorrect. We should do the set data part outside these if-else conditions pref using View Holders.

Comment: @rahul: yes at a time only 5 rows are visible on the screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this..   just write all code out of the condition expect inflate code..

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null){
            Log.v("pos", ""+position);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.e_lesion_liststyle, null);   
           }       //end of if condition
            final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.disease_lesion_checkbox);
            cb.setText(mData.get(position));
            cb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View v) {
                    cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.check_box_1);
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: @CapDroid I'm quite new to databinding to a view in android and am coming from the .net repeater style with C#. Could you tell me about the R.layout.e_lesion_liststyle? I'm guessing it's a generic layout that is used to repeat the given string data on? Thank you in advanced.

For instance, I have an array list of type LocationHistory, an object that has mostly strings that I would like to display each row in some sort of view on a layout. Other than changing the type of data in adapter class, do I have to create a generic layout that inflates onto a main layout with the LocationHistory data?